# Biggest Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, statistics

Are there some statistics about number of users, number of questions, etc. on different Stack Exchange sites?

I'm interested in seeing which are the biggest ones and how far behind are the others. I can assume Stack Overflow is the biggest, but I have no idea what comes next.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple, go to https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic and sort by the statistic you want:

[image]

Other statistics (such as total reputation of all users) probably require a cross-site [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) query.

Comment: kinda amusing how much bigger mathematics is than SU in terms of questions and answers, but not traffic ;p